# Filtered file viewer

Tags: linux, less

I'm using the `less` to view log files. This is quite good, but I want to filter out some lines from output. E.g. I don't want to see lines containing "DEBUG" or I want see lines which contain only "[pool-9-thread-4]".

Is there easy way to do it? Is there any more advanced tool to work with log files?

I know solution as `grep 'pool-9-thread-4' my.log | less`, but it is not good enough - I cannot change filtering criteria and it works slow for large files.

Answer (score 0):

A list of characters enclosed by `[` and `]` is called `bracket expression`.
For example, the regular expression `[0123456789]` matches any single digit.
You should escape `[]` to get literal value:

```
$ grep '\[pool-9-thread-4\]' my.log | less
```

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right about the brakets, just a typo, but it is not related to my question.